# How do I write a Hadoop map reduce job without using deprecated classes?

Tags: java, hadoop

I know it's my OCD, but I can't stand to have a deprecated reference in my code.

That said, the Hadoop tutorials, including the "The Definitive Guide" book, uses only deprecated classes JobConf and classes from the mapred package that are all deprecated.

Nowhere can I find any text on how to convert an existing MapReduce job to use the new construct.

Answer (score 1):

I talked with the Cloudera people short time ago and they confirmed that the "new" functionality is incomplete and there's no way to write serious Hadoop stuff without using the "deprecated" packages.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with 0.20.2. Unless you are not using some fancy join stuff.
`JobConf` for example is deprecated because you can use `Configuration`. Or the old `Mapper` interface is now a class that is representing the old identity mapper.

Simple answer: you have to look through the java docs and see what the replacement actually is.